# how to write the output of an execute SQL task in to a flat file SSIS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have created an SSIS package which includes an Execute SQL Task which executes the DBCC checkdb. Now , I want to write the output of this task into a flat file.

I tried my best but couldnt find any way to collect the output of the executed task or any means to move the output of a task in control flow to the data flow task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is possible . You need to map it to the ResultSet

Comment: I had a similar issue. In the Execute Sql property window, you will find ResultSet . Populate it with a variable. You can get pointers from http://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Data Flow task instead of an Execute SQL task. In the Data Flow Task setup a Source OLE DB component connected to your Flat File destination component. The source OLE DB component will contain the same query as your Execute SQL query.